# Performance testing scenarios required

Tags: performance, optimization, testing

What can be the various performance testing scenarios to be considered for a website with huge traffic? Is there any way to identify the elements of the code which are adversely affecting the site performance?

Please provide something similar to checklist of generalised scenarios to be tested to ensure proper performance testing.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to start with some load testing tools like [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) or [PushToTest](http://pushtotest.com) and start running it against your web application. JMeter simulates HTTP traffic and loads the server that way. You can do that as well as load test AJAX parts of your application with PushToTest because it can use Selenium Scripts.

If you don't have the resources (computers to run load tests) you can always use a service like [BrowserMob](http://www.browsermob.com) to run the scripts against a web accessible server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need more of a test plan than a suggestion of tools to use.  In performance testing, it is best to look at the users of the application -

- **How many** will use the application on a light day?  How many will use the app on a heavy day?
- **What type of users** make up your user population?
- **What transactions** will each of these user types perform?

Using this information, you can identify the major transactions and come up with different user levels (e.g. 10, 25, 50, 100) and percentages of user types (30% user A, 50% user B, ...) to test these transactions with.  Time each of these transactions for each test you execute and examine how the transaction times change as compared to your user levels.

After gathering some metrics, since you should be able to narrow transactions to individual pieces of code, you will be able to know where to focus your code improvements.  If you still need to narrow things down further, finer tests within each transaction can be created to provide more granular results.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency will kill you here, as you need to test your maximum projected concurrent users + wiggling room hitting the database, website, and any other web service simultaneously. It really depends on the technologies you're using, but if you have a large interaction of different web technologies, you may want to check out [Neoload](http://www.neotys.com). I've had nothing but success with this web stress tool, and the support is top notch if you need to emulate specific, complicated behavior (such as mocking AMF traffic, or using responses from web pages to dictate request behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DB layer then this should be the initial focus of your attention, once the system is stable (i.e. no memory leaks or other resource issues). If the DB is not the bottle neck (or not relevant) then you need to correlate CPU/Memory/Disk IO and Network traffic with the increasing load and increasing response times. This gives you an idea of capacity and correlation (but not cause) to resource usage.

To find the cause of a given issue with resources you need to establish a Six Sigma style project where you define the problem and perform root case analysis in order to pin point the piece of code (or resource configuration) that is the bottleneck. Once you have done this a couple of times in your environment, you will notice patterns of workload, resource usage and counter measures (solutions) that will guide you in your future performance testing 'projects'.

Answer (score 0):

To choose correct performance scenarios you need to go through the next basic checklist:

- High priority scenarios from the business logic perspective. For example: login/order transactions, etc.
- Mostly used scenarios by end users. Here you may need information from monitoring tools like NewRelic, etc.
- Search / filtering functionality (if applicable) - Scenarios which involve different user roles/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Performance test is a comparison test either with the previous release of the same application or with the existing players in the market.

**Case 1- Existing application**

1)Carry out the test for the same scenarios as covered before to get a clear picture on the response of the application before and after the upgrade.

2)If you need to dig deeper you can get back to the database team to understand which functionalities are getting more requests. Also ask them on the total number of requests on an average on any particular day so that you can take a call on what user load and time duration to be given for the test.

**Case 2- New Application**

1) Look for existing market players and design your test as per the critical functions of the rival product (for e.g. Gmail might support many functions what what is being used often is launch ->login ->compose mail -> inbox ->outbox).

2) Any time you can get back to your clients on what they suppose to be business critical scenarios or scenarios that will be used more often..